# AngularJS cannot read property 'releasesList' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I tried to make my code work but I had zero luck.
This is my code:

```
class ReleasesController{
    constructor(API,$rootScope,$scope){
        'ngInject';
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.$scope = $scope;
        this.API = API;
    }

    $onInit(){
        this.releasesList= [];
        this.API.all(this.$rootScope.type).get('').then((response) => {
            _.each(response, function (release) {
                _.each(release.releases, function (videorelease) {
                    this.releasesList.push({
                        name: release.name,
                        image: release.image,
                        views: videorelease.views,
                        hash: videorelease.hash,
                        episode: videorelease.episode
                    });
                });
            });
        })
    }
}

export const ReleasesComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/releases/releases.component.html',
    controller: ReleasesController,
    controllerAs: 'rs',
    bindings: {}
};
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'releasesList' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://website.dev/js/final.js:127247:1), <anonymous>:33:21)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://website.dev/js/final.js:61512:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://website.dev/js/final.js:127247:1), <anonymous>:32:15)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://website.dev/js/final.js:61512:9)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://website.dev/js/final.js:127247:1), <anonymous>:31:11)
    at processQueue (http://website.dev/js/final.js:16648:37)
    at http://website.dev/js/final.js:16692:27
    at Scope.$eval (http://website.dev/js/final.js:17972:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://website.dev/js/final.js:17786:31)
    at Scope.scopePrototype.$digest (chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js:1364:23) Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

I tried in to debug it and I don't know why the variable is `undefined`.
Can anyone explain me?

Comment: i think that this.releasesList has changed the context inside inside the _.each function meaning it's undefined. try to use an arrow function.

Comment: Use fat-arrow `=>` functions to preserve `this` binding.

Comment: can you declare the releaseList before the constructor before using it in ngOnInit() and see if that makes a difference? `releasesList;`

Comment: Thanks guys arrow function worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) says about arrow functions:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target. These function expressions are best suited for non-method
>   functions, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Means, arrow function will help to **not have a unique object instance on child objects/functions** -> your child object/function will preserver your parents object instance. This is possible since ECMAScript6 and its absolutely nice. ON default your parent instance `this` is not available in other objects / functions in JavaScript but by using arrow function your parent object arguments will be parsed into your childs object/function.

```
$onInit(){
    this.releasesList= [];
    this.API.all(this.$rootScope.type).get('').then((response) => {
        _.each(response, (release) => {
            _.each(release.releases, (videorelease) => {
                this.releasesList.push({
                    name: release.name,
                    image: release.image,
                    views: videorelease.views,
                    hash: videorelease.hash,
                    episode: videorelease.episode
                });
            });
        });
    })
}
```

Before ECMAScript6 you need to make it work with an "global" function var like  `self = this` where `var self` stores your object instance and is available as a global var in your child functions/objects:

```
$onInit(){

    this.releasesList= [];
    var self = this;

    this.API.all(this.$rootScope.type).get('').then(function (response) {
        _.each(response, function (release) {
            _.each(release.releases, function (videorelease) {
                self.releasesList.push({
                    name: release.name,
                    image: release.image,
                    views: videorelease.views,
                    hash: videorelease.hash,
                    episode: videorelease.episode
                });
            });
        });
    })
}
```